# PageViewController crashes on rotation

Tags: ios

Hi I have a pageViewcontroller with some viewcontrollers inside. There ara blank controllers with one label inside

Problem is that it crashes when I try to rotate it

Here is the code

```
class FAPageViewController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = ["one", "two"]

var pageViewController = UIPageViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pages.removeAll()
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var obj = "child"
        pages.append(obj)
    }

    pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + 64, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 64)

    addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

    pageViewController.delegate = self
    pageViewController.dataSource = self

    pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewcontrollerAtIndex(0)], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    print(pages)


}

func viewcontrollerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(pages[index])
    return vc!
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {

        if index < pages.count - 1 {
            return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index + 1)
        }

    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {

        if index > 0 {
            return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index - 1)
        }

    }

    return nil
}

}
```

Here is console log

> 2016-03-13 14:19:16.743 FacebookAlbums[7550:1624956] *** Assertion failure in -[FacebookAlbums.FAPageViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UIPageViewController.m:1062
>   2016-03-13 14:19:16.748 FacebookAlbums[7550:1624956] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No view controllers'

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it: I set up the UIPageViewController once again (exactly like when we did the first time) in the event of device rotation by adding the following method to UIPageViewController implementation file:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Because most of the time, UIPageViewController is modally presented, so on device rotation, this controller will be called again.

Comment: this worked for me thanks you, worked in swift 4.1. no idea why. just had to add this empty method

Answer (score 2):

I also had an app that subclassed UIPageViewController. I had been using it for years but we had always limited it to Portrait mode. I recently began another project that started with this as a base but in this case we DID want to allow landscape modes. The app has a Navigation Controller and a couple of initial screens and then pushes to the PageViewController. The rotations would work with the conventional VC's on the Top of the Navigation Controller but if I tried rotation with the PageViewController displaying, I'd get an exception:

2020-07-24 19:33:01.440876-0400 MAT-sf[68574:12477921] *** Assertion failure in -[MAT_sf.SurveyVC willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3920.31.102/UIPageViewController.m:1055
2020-07-24 19:33:01.454443-0400 MAT-sf[68574:12477921] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No view controllers'

It turns out that all I had to do was add an override to my subclass:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

All it does is call the same function in the superclass. I'm guessing that this should be a required method if you subclass PageViewController.

Hope this helps someone. This one cost me about a day of research until I stumbled on the solution.

Comment: This approach solved my case. It isn't clear why it works, but I'm thankful that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks HSH, I had the same problem in Xamarin.
I implemented:

```
public override void WillAnimateRotation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)
{
}
```

Leaving it empty, prevents it from calling the base method. Which apparently does something that makes it crash.
Implementing this override method without calling the base method, works for me. I had a similar exception when changing the orientation quickly.

```
(MonoTouchException) Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: No view controllers
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113e3302e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000114b7cb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113e32da8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001113a3b61 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001208b32c6 -[UIPageViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 3983
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000120960d3e -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 294
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000012095d060 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext __runAlongsideAnimations] + 263
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000012148862a +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 528
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000121488bd9 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 99
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000120975276 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 278
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000012148c788 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:forScene:] + 174
    11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120975004 __58-[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 164
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000012148862a +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 528
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000121488bd9 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 99
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120974edc -[_UIWindowRotationAnimationController animateTransition:] + 491
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120fefef9 -[UIWindow _rotateToBounds:withAnimator:transitionContext:] + 525
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120ff293c -[UIWindow _rotateWindowToOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:skipCallbacks:] + 2331
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120ff2f2f -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 633
    18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120ff1e83 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 119
    19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120ff0d00 __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 111
    20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000120ff0c29 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 455
    21  Foundation                          0x0000000111426976 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 420
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113d96944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113d96632 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113d95c8a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113d909fe
```